# When closing node (geth ropsten) I cannot save created accounts

Tags: web3js, truffle, accounts, nodes, ropsten

I am pretty new to this. I downloaded the ropsten blockchain using a geth command line. Then, using Truffle, I created an account, but when I closed my node (ctrl - c on the geth command line) and then re-opened it I couldn't see my account in Truffle anymore. 
How can I close my node and open it again and still keep the accounts I create?
Thank you

Comment: How did you create an account with truffle? Are you sure you are connecting truffle with ropsten? Truffle now has its own private network, perhaps you are using it instead of ropsten.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have completely downloaded the entire blockchain of testnet.
You can Check this by entering into Truffle console and put the command '*web3.eth.syncing*',
 if you are completely downloaded then it returns the details of blockchain like the nodes, size etc.
if the download is not completed then it returns 'false'
**Note that the truffle only get your testnet account after you completed the downloading of entire blockchain**